# Java Jackson DeserializationFeature

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have problem with Jackson and DeserializationFeature. From WebService I get JSON field like:

```
"location":null,
```

OR

```
    "location":{
            "code":"YYYYYY",
            "label":"XXXXXX"
            },
```

When I try get code or label eg.

```
project.getLocation().getCode();
```

Java return NullPointerException.

My current code is written like eg. and its work fine.

```
        if (project.getLocation() != null) {
            location_code = project.getLocation().getCode();
            location_label = project.getLocation().getLabel();
        } else {
            location_code = null;
            location_label = null;
        }
```

Which option of DeserializationFeature is right for this problem?

Comment: When you say `DeserializationFeature`, what exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about DeserializationFuture option, but simple null check could do the job:

```
String code = null;
Location location = project.getLocation(); // maybe, some yours location type
if (location != null) {
    code = location.getCode();
}
```

Comment: My current code is written like your example. if (project.location != null) getCode and its work fine. I thought it was some other way.